# Evaluating $\cot\fracπ{24}$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

Let $\theta=\fracπ{24}$

$2\theta=\fracπ{12}$

$\tan2\theta=\tan\fracπ{12}$

$\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}=2-√3$

$2\tan\theta=(2-√3)-(2-√3)\tan^2\theta$

$(2-√3)\tan^2\theta+2\tan\theta-(2-√3)=0$

$\tan\theta=\frac{-2±\sqrt{4+4(4-3)}}{2(2-√3)}$

$\tan\theta=\frac{-1±√2}{2-√3}$

Therefore, $\cot\theta=\frac{2-√3}{√2-1}$

Rationalising,

$\cot\fracπ{24}=(2-√3)(√2+1)=√8-√6+√4-√3$

But as per [this link](https://www.sarthaks.com/1254047/prove-that-cot-pi-24-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-sqrt-4-sqrt-6), $\cot\fracπ{24}=√2+√3+√4+√6$

What's my mistake here?

Comment: There's a mistake in the $4ac$ term of the discriminant: $(2-\sqrt3)^2=7-4\sqrt3\neq1$

Comment: Agree with @user170231. Maybe you mistakenly used $2+\sqrt{3}$ for one of your $2-\sqrt{3}$ factors.

Comment: @user170231 thank you very much.

Comment: @J.G. yes, that's what had I done. Facepalm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution

$$\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}=\frac{\color{red}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\color{red}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}}{\color{red}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\color{red}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}}=\frac{2 \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}$$

But $\sin (2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2\theta-1\implies 2\cos^2\theta=\cos(2\theta)+1$,
hence

$$\frac{2 \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)}=\frac{\cos\left(2\cdot \frac{\pi}{24}\right)+1}{\sin\left(2\cdot \frac{\pi}{24}\right)}=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)+1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}$$

Knowing that $\frac{\pi}{12}=15°$ we have:
$$\sin(15°)=\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}, \quad \cos(15°)=\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2\sqrt 2}$$
$$\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)=\frac{\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2\sqrt 2}+1}{\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}}=2+\sqrt 3+\sqrt 6+\sqrt 2$$